# New Istanbul airport international transfer with Turkish Airlines 1hr 5mins enough?

Tags: transit, short-connections, ist

I am hoping that I can get some advice as I am considering to book a flight with Turkish Airlines from London to Luxor, Egypt with a transfer at the new Istanbul

- Airport- the transfer time at Istanbul airport is only 1hr 5 minutes. Is this really enough time?
- Has anyone experienced such a short transfer time at this new airport and made their international connecting flight?
- Is there any chance of getting a buggy to drive us between the terminals as it will quicker than on foot?

Comment: Yes I have done this thrice you ll have to walk a lot depending on your gate but its doable. The airport is massive though.

Comment: Is it all on one ticket? If so, should be fine in the sense that they'll put you on the next flight if you do in fact miss it.